# The resource cannot be found. Description: HTTP 404.

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3

I am new in net. I am trying to do a web site.

I run my project in local... I create a class a view , y create a method Edit and the view but when a run the aplication I obtain this error.

The resource cannot be found.

Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.

Requested URL: /AdmiController/Edit

Any idea!!! thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should that not be Admin/Edit
You have a typo in the name part, and the "controller" is not needed because of the conventions that mvc uses